# Move_uploaded_file() not working, no error, on Google Compute Engine

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

Move_uploaded_file() not working, no error, on Google Compute Engine
(It works in other vm):

CentOS 7.2 / LAMP

Just move to Google Compute Engine, Move_uploaded_file() doesn't work anymore.

Firewall is off, folder www and tmp are 777

Here's my code:

```
$uploads_dir = "./photo";
$tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
$file_name = $photo_name.".jpg";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$file_name");
```

Deeply appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved by disable selinux.